# How do I set the dataframe in R to Excel preserving design(original excel file)?

Tags: excel, output, xlsx, xlconnect

I want to add a data frame to an existing Excel document.

```
cd <- xlsx::loadWorkbook("abcde.xlsx")
cdsh <- xlsx::getSheets(cd)
sheet <- cdsh[[1]]
```

I want to split the R data into 2 sectors in Excel.

Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

My R data frame:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know that in the package 'XLConnect' preserving the formatting is possible.

You could do something like:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("PathToFile/abcde.xlsx", create = TRUE)

setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")

readWorksheet(wb, "cd")

writeWorksheet(wb, "cd", data= DataforFirstRegion, startRow= 5, startCol = 3)
writeWorksheet(wb, "cd", data= Data2forSecondRegion, startRow= 12, startCol = 3)

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

That is using the values of the current setup displayed in your photos. 
the second command, setStyleAction() is the command that will leave the formatting untouched by the XLConnect process.

Hope that helps!